# RabbitMQ vs NoSQL?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, nosql

I was just wondering why would you use a something like RabbitMQ instead of a persistent store especially a document store like MongoDB? Arent they kinda the same? Whats the benefit of something like RabbitMQ over a database?

Would anyone who used something like RabbitMQ elaborate on the benefits?

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ is a message broker software aka **a queue** and not a NoSql database!

While the trend goes towards storing more and more data in scaled-up queues as well as processing data at real time and thus obliterating the need for additional data storage, queues are not to be confused with databases:

- most queues don't persist data indefinitely.
- the data in queues is not available on demand by the use of queries, but accessed via an automatically triggered consumer mechanism.
- the **architectural intention** behind queues differs tremendously from that of databases. Their purpose in a system's architecture is not data storage, but system integration and data distribution. For more good information on queue architecture, please check [this article](http://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-data-platform-1/) from the Kafka guys.